# What does the emergence of different interpretations of Wittgenstein signify?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, wittgenstein, interpretation, natural-language

So I was listening to this [Podcast](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p0054945) about Wittgenstein the speakers are the Professor of Philosophy of University of South Hampton - Ray Monk, Senior Lecturer of University of York - Mary Macgin and Bary Smith Senior Lecturer of Philosophy London. It seems all 3 philosophers cannot agree on the fine points of Wittgenstein.

Given Wittgenstein used the notion of language games to argue that one does not need to define them (language games) itself and a lot of other terms. Can the emergence of different interpretations of Wittgenstein be seen as a failure of his thesis? Or does one argue with the change in times different language games are being played and thus the essence is lost? (Which would then make Socrates question "what is justice?" relevant all over again but additionally meaningful with emergence of any new language game)

Comment: "different versions" of Wittgenstein maybe means that [Wittgenstein's thought](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein/) changed in time (a fact quite common to most philosophers).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA in the podcast they are talking mostly about Philosophical Investigations

Comment: Do you mean that "different versions" means different interpretations? Alos this is common to **every** philosopher.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA yes "different interpretations" (i'll edit the question). I was loosely aware of this phenomena but I think the question articulates it well why this should be specially relevant to Wittgenstein?

Comment: The basic reason that every philosophical text is complex and natural language *per se* is subject to multiple interpretations; thus, we can read the same text from different points of view, with different backgrounds and with different "expectations"

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA are you saying: "Or does one argue with the change in times different language games are being played and thus the essence is lost?" what do you make of the "(Which would then make Socrates question "what is justice?" relevant all over again but additionally meaningful with emergence of any new language game)"?

Comment: Basically two issues: (i) ["later" W](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein/#LateWitt) introduced *language games* to elucidate the way language works (it is obvious that we **do not** language by "definitions"), and (ii) to correct his previous point of view that we can achieve a "perfectly logical" language where all is unambiguous and meaningful.

Comment: The "side effect" of this approach is that the concept of *language game* itself is not defined (it is not possible to define it) but introduced "by example".

Comment: Having said that, we may imagine the "philosophical language game" where we ask the question: "What is justice?" and we have different answers, from Socrates up to current times. May we say that the "meaning" of *justice* changed over time? It is reasonable to answer YES.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA fair. The question would then become was the introduction of these concepts via example sufficient?

Comment: Also about justice: "Philosophers, Wittgenstein believed, had been misled into thinking that their subject was a kind of science, a search for theoretical explanations of the things that puzzled them: the nature of meaning, truth, mind, time, justice, and so on. " (my mention of Socrates justice was about this)

Comment: Also as you correctly state: it is not possible to define it. I would say that "philosophical language game" is actually consists of different language games: "philosophical language game: Greek Era Version" and "philosophical language game: Modern Take"

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I don't disagree about anything you've said here, but I think it is worth noting that the question of whether/how much "late" Wittgenstein's thought differs from the author of the Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus (& if so, on what) is itself one of the contentious issues in e.g. the ["New Wittgenstein" debate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Wittgenstein) (with so-called "resolute readers" like Cora Diamond or James Conant arguing for substantial continuity between "early" & "late" W., critics like PMS Hacker & Ian Proops arguing for discontinuity / difference, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does the emergence of different interpretations of Wittgenstein signify?

I'm going to answer the question from a different angle: the competition of interpretations have nothing to do with Wittgenstein's work per se, though his work may illuminate why multiple interpretations occur.

In the broadest sense, it signifies properties of natural language: [ambiguity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguity) and [vagueness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagueness). But, I'd add a third significant factor: [first principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_principle). That Wittgenstein, particularly through his notions of [family resemblance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_resemblance), has shaped the conversation that resulted in the [linguistic turn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_turn) or, say, the nature of definition (particularly through [prototype theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_theory)), in modern linguistics is coincident.

Philosophical arguments come in roughly two flavors: one, where everyone agrees on the general ideas that go into *a posteriori* reasoning, and two, where there's much ado made about *a priori* reasoning that precedes discussion. In linguistics, one might hear the phrase 'semantic frame'. In rhetoric, this is observed in the notion of 'framing a debate'. In law, one often hears about 'arguing the facts'. Most broadly, sociologists call this (unsurprisingly) [framing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framing_(social_sciences)). From WP:

> In the social sciences, framing comprises a set of concepts and theoretical perspectives on how individuals, groups, and societies organize, perceive, and communicate about reality.

In the language of logic and argumentation theory, one could say there are arguments about premises, and there are arguments about inference. And in fact, to make things more confusing, since there is a body of theory about inference itself, one can argue about premises related to inferences, and about inferences about inference. The end result of this is that philosophical discourse which is conducted through natural language is inherently open to interpretation, an idea that snaked its way right into modern philosophy in ways such [indeterminancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminacy_(philosophy)) of translation and [underdetermination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermination) of theory being two.

> Can the emergence of different interpretations of Wittgenstein be seen as a failure of his thesis?

Not at all. Actually it's a confirmation. You invoke the notion of language games, and to distill, this is just the notion that agents who use language derive and invent meaning based on a [normative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normativity) or [goal-oriented basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleology). That is, it is important to see language as an exchange of sound with the agendas of the agents involved, a notion that is in essence an organizing principle of [pragmatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics). And if different agents (read philosophers) have different values and goals, shouldn't we expect that they attempt to create and use language to achieve different ends, and thus they differ in their artifacts such as definitions and theories? Of course!

Furthermore, this is important to understand, because it leads into a very revolutionary idea at the time, the notion that the meaning of language, semantics, is not strictly speaking a property of an entity called language, but a process of interpretation of agency. This is part of the focus of the linguistic turn, where the [philosophy of language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_language) experienced some serious growth.

Of course, this wouldn't surprise LW at all. The preface to Tractatus starts thusly:

> Perhaps this book will be understood only by someone who has himself already had the thoughts that are expressed in it -- or at least similar thoughts.

So, what's up with the interpretations of LW's work? Maybe the best starting point to answer that question is what's up with the interpretations of Aristotle's? Plato's? Kant's? Russell's? What's up with the nature of language and interpretation to begin with?

Comment: I feel this answer could be used for religious scripture as well. So is it possible one interprets Wittgenstein in a way Wittgenstein did not intend? And is that legitimate?

Comment: Also thanks for your regular wonderful answers on this community :) some of which I am the beneficiary of

Comment: Your welcome. We are here in a cooperative venture to lift discourse on the Internet beyond the Kardashians and cat videos, and insofar as everyone participates in our community, the world is a better place. Thus, I owe you the same quality and quantity of thanks...

Comment: As for the former, it boils down to your views of "legitimacy". I am a pluralist in many regards, and I don't see a problem with philosophy entertaining multiple interpretations of a theory. In fact, I see it as a strength. Were LW still alive, he might rebut claims, or even change his positions a third time, but be that as it may, it is the discourse of disagreement itself that I believe is the strength of philosophy as a practice (my metaphilosophical views). Certainly, we should use language games by their context. In heart surgery, miasma theory should be rejected for germ theory...

Comment: there are ethical considerations, after all, for being "right" and "wrong". But on musings about the interpretation of language and theory, should we not engage in a healthy debate and build consensus? In this regard I reject absolutism, and I'd encourage you to do the same. My simple advice is divide reality up into perceptual and conceptual components, and defend the notion of a single physical reality we share, but a pluralism of theories that describe it (as long as no one is harmed, of course. :D)

Comment: As for your religious comments, read Paul Ross's profile. He's bright and surely would agree with you. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/3867/paul-ross

Answer (score 2):

If you want to understand the situation around Wittgenstein's work, you are going to have to study it. I put a list of resources, and introductory remarks to his work, in this post here: [Introductory lectures to Wittgenstein's ideas](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/86373/introductory-lectures-to-wittgensteins-ideas/86378#86378)

The Private Language Argument, which I would argue is the most significant contribution by Wittgenstein, was developed from just a few of his late remarks, and the 'Beetle in a Box' thought experiment. It's the very opposite of a failure, to have made such a fundamentally simple, provocative point, that has implications towards the foundations of how we think. Wittgenstein ruthlessly avoided jargon, and used the minimum of words - and that can make his remarks seem deceptively simple. They are not.

Different interpretations of Wittgenstein have indeed flourished. See [The New Wittgenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Wittgenstein), for a key step in the development, particularly in recasting the link between his early and late work. Personally, I follow the 'resolute reading', that "some of the propositions of the Tractatus are withheld from self-application, they are not themselves nonsense, but point out the nonsensical nature of the Tractatus" quoted from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractatus_Logico-Philosophicus#Proposition_6.N). Which relates to his later works not repudiating the Tractatus, but fundamentally sharing purposes with it.

I really like this article about what he was at with describing the Tractatus as a ladder to be thrown away after use: [Nāgārjuna, Nietzsche, and Rorty’s Strange Looping Trick](https://absoluteirony.wordpress.com/2014/09/17/nagarjuna-nietzsche-rorty-and-their-strange-looping-trick/amp/). I see a deep kinship between Wittgenstein's work, and Hofstadter's ideas of strange-loops and tangled-hierarchies, and that style of observing patterns of thought.

I regard a great deal of Wittgenstein's import as being from his provocations, from his asking questions, not his answering of them. That is surely like Socrates, and no mark of failure in philosophy.

Comment: While you definitely answer it cannot be seen as a failure of his thesis. Is the conclusion we celebrate the questions Wittgenstein's questions as worthy of consideration, thought and the philosophical endeavor?

Comment: But regardless thanks for your study material :)

Comment: @MoreAnonymous: Yes.  He is *pointing* towards truths that are unsayable, I see that as his thesis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractatus_Logico-Philosophicus#Proposition_7